# How to deal with unintended request methods in python?

Tags: django

Suppose that I have a views that should only respond to GET requests:

```
def myview(request, topic_id):
    if request.method == "GET": 
         #do something
         #return  some url 
   else:
         #What should I do here to have the least performance or security issues?
```

Comment: Return an http error that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [HttpResponseNotAllowed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed):

```
def my_view(request, topic_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # do domething
        pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['GET'])
```

Comment: Nice one. Thanks. I prefer this to decorators.

Comment: Strange, because this is _exactly_ what the decorator does for you... ;-)

Comment: I really recommend to use CBV, but OP does not like them.

Comment: @Ben this method may have an advantage in cases when you already have a decorator. Because this helps avoids unintended consequences of wrong ordering of decorators.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the decorators Django provides to limit what method types are allowed:

```
from django.views.decorators import require_GET

@require_GET
def myview(request, topic_id):
    # Guaranteed to be GET only
```

Django will raise a 405 Method Not Allowed for any other methods.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Ben's recommendation, you can also use a class-based view, which will do this for you. For example:

```
from django.views.generic import View


class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only the GET method will work. Others will return a 405.
```

Although it should be noted that you would not generally use the base `View` just by itself. The other generic class-based views, such as `TemplateView`, `ListView`, and `DetailView` are usually far more desirable.

Comment: Thanks but I don't like CBF, as they reminds me of java!